# How do I use my original account with a new install?

Tags: diablo-iii

I had Diablo 3 on my computer but then I reset my computer back to factory, lost all my info, and no longer have that disc or key code. So I bought a new copy and key code. Is there any way to upload my previous characters onto my new copy? I still have the same battle.net account.

Comment: I believe you should open a ticket on Blizzard for that, They are really fast in replaying and solving this kind of problem

Comment: The installation key associated with your old installation should be forever bound to your battle.net account (which you would have had to have created to play the game at all), if you log into that account via their website you should be able to download the game client. Then just open the battle.net launcher and put in your old credentials (read: username and password). There's no reason to get a new copy of the game unless you were banned by Blizzard, so get a refund if you still can.

Comment: If you already registered your new key code to your battle.net account, you may have to contact Blizzard to get the old one back.  If not, as others said, you don't need the new copy.  Don't do anything with the new key code.  Just go to your local battle.net site (us, eu, etc.), log in, go to the Diablo 3 page, and download the game client via the link provided.  After installing it, just use your battle.net credentials to log in.

Answer (score 4):

Blizzard games are bound to your battle.net account. You should return the new copy of the game and just log into your battle.net account and download the client. You then just sign into your account like you always have before and everything should be right where you left it.

Comment: I hope for their sake that they *can* return it...Blizzard games aren't cheap!

Comment: Only the new games are actually bound to account. Old ones like Diablo, Diablo II and probably Starcraft, Warcraft and Warcraft 2 still work based on CD-KEYs

Comment: @Novarg You can still bind the older game CD keys to your battle.net account if you so choose - I have.

Comment: @Novarg As JonK said, you can bind them if you want to. I have Diablo II and all the DLCs and such registered with my battle.net account as well... So the discs just sit quietly on my shelf.